# Does this person get electrified?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

Does a person get electrified when his feet are on the floor, his right hand is holding $220~V$ and his left hand holding a piece of wood or any other insulator?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ground to be at $0 V$, there is a potential difference of $220V$ between the person's right hand and the ground. The only way to prevent an electric current to flow from his right hand to the ground is if the pathways of current between those two are insulated, blocking the path of current. Holding an insulator in the left hand does not prevent electrocution because that insulator is not even in the path of current.

In order to prevent electrocution, insulation between the person's feet and the ground is the best option: it will remove the possible pathways of current from the right hand to the ground. However, this is only the case for objects with a sufficiently high value of dielectric strength. Otherwise the electric field strength due to the potential difference will cause dielectric breakdown in the insulator, and the insulating material will no longer insulate.